# How many ways are there to pick a selection of $1 worth of identical...

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to pick a selection of $\$1$ worth of identical pennies,  $\$1$ worth of identical nickels,  $\$1$ worth of identical dimes if you select a total of $16$ coins?

Soln: At first the quantities threw me off when they provided too much information,  but the key word is identical which means I do not have to choose between the elements.  That being said I applied the bars and stars method arriving at: $C(16 + 3 - 1, 16) = 
C( 16 + 3 - 1, 2)$

but looking at their solution they had: $C(16 + 3 - 1, 16) - C(5 + 3 - 1, 5)$

Is it a possible solution typo?  I don't see where or why they subtracted,  unless they wanted to ask "how many of a certain amount of coin given that there must be at least of coin X"

Comment: You cannot choose more than ten $10c$ coins

Comment: why can't you?  Is it saying the the maximum value that my coins must have is $1? If so why subtract that amount there?

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  Are you saying that there $100$ pennies, $20$ nickels, and $10$ dimes and that your mission is to choose $16$ total coins?  Or are you saying something else?

Comment: yes that is exactly what I am saying.  But the pennies are all identical,  as are the nickels  and dimes.  There is a first part to the question that asks about 9 coins instead of 16. That solution was C(9 + 3 - 1, 9). So I found it odd they would ask the same question just with a larger quantity.

Comment: As the earlier comment suggests, there is a big difference between $9$ and $16$.  There are only ten dimes, so you can't choose more than ten of them.  That constraint is irrelevant if you only want nine coins, but it matters if you want sixteen.

Comment: So what we subtracted out was what?  All the ways that more than 10 dimes could've been slelected if they existed?

Comment: Exactly.  The first term is the "unconstrained" answer.  To use the constraint you have to subtract all the combinations which used $11$ or more dimes.  (Hint: think about the unconstrained problem...knowing that you used $11$ dimes means that you are now trying to pick $5$ coins from an unlimited supply of pennies, nickels, and dimes).

Comment: Makes sense,  now wrapping my head around the scenario for future use will take a little bit to feel comfortable with.  Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarising my comment and lulu's various comments:

- If you could use any number of pennies, nickels and dimes, then there would, as you say, be $C(16 + 3 - 1, 16) = C( 16 + 3 - 1, 2)=153$ possibilities of choosing $16$ of them, using a stars-and-bars argument.
- But you only have ten dimes ($\$1$ worth of identical $10c$ coins).  So you need to subtract cases with eleven  or more dimes.  The number of cases with $11$ or more dimes is $C((16-11) + 3 - 1, (16-11)) = C( 5+ 3 - 1, 5)=21$, again using a stars-and-bars argument.
- You do not have an additional constraint from the $20$ nickels or $100$ pennies as you are only selecting $16$ coins.

So the answer is $C(16 + 3 - 1, 16)-C( 5+ 3 - 1, 5) = 132$ possibilities.